# Why does the script work on a Notepad window, but not on an Explorer window and other program windows?

Tags: windows, script, automation, autohotkey

I found some code that works in the notepad, but can't work in the explorer and some other software, how to change it to universal?Or is there some other way, to scroll the number of lines without going through the scroll wheel event?

```
lines := 43
loop, %lines%
{
SendMessage, 0x115, 1, 0, %control%, A
}
```

---

```
ScrollLines(43)(43)

returnreturn

 

ScrollLines(lines,hWnd="") {ScrollLines(lines,hWnd="") {

 static EM_LINESCROLL := 0xB6static EM_LINESCROLL := 0xB6

 if !hWndif !hWnd

 {{

  ControlGetFocus, c, AControlGetFocus, c, A

  ControlGet, hWnd, hWnd, , %c%, AControlGet, hWnd, hWnd, , %c%, A

 }}

 PostMessage, EM_LINESCROLL, 0, lines-1, , ahk_id %hWnd%   ; 'lines-1' makes the line you wish to jump to visiblePostMessage, EM_LINESCROLL, 0, lines-1, , ahk_id %hWnd%   ; 'lines-1' makes the line you wish to jump to visible

 returnreturn

}}
```

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. The state your question is currently in, is very confusing. Can you edit your question and provide more information and clarity about what you try to accomplish and what tools you are using? The tags mention autohotkey and autoit, 2 very different software packages. If you are using both, please limit your question to just one of them.

Comment: It's an autohotkey script, I edited it, sorry.

Comment: EM_LINESCROLL belongs to edit controls (just read the Windows API documentation on that entry). So it will only work on text fields like the one from Notepad but not on ListViews or TreeViews like Explorer uses.

Comment: Thanks, I get it, but the first script doesn't use EM_LINESCROLL, why doesn't it work? Is there any code to scroll by line count that works for the explorer?